# von Neumann-Liouville expansion in Quantume Field Theory

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, mathematical-physics, unbounded-operators

Here are two questions related to the following form
$$U(t,t_0)=1+(\frac{-i}{\hbar})\int_{t_0}^tdt'\,H^I_1(t')U(t',t_0) \tag{1}$$
This is known as the iterative form of solution to the differential equation for operators:
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}U(t,t_0)=H^I_1(t)U(t,t_0)
$$
where $H^I_1(t)$ is known as the Hamiltonian in the interaction picture. $U(t_0,t_0)=1$ ($U, H, 1$ are operators).

Now my question is, suppose we know the following property of $U(t,t_0):$
$$U(t,t_1)U(t_1,t_0)=U(t,t_0)
$$
for arbitrary $t,\,t_1$ and $t_0$. Or $U(t,t_0)$ is a flow. Can we use the flow property together with $(1)$ to obtain the solution:
$$U(t,t_0)=1+(\frac{-i}{\hbar})\int^t_{t_0}dt_1H^I_1(t_1)+(\frac{-i}{\hbar})^2\int^t_{t_0}dt_1\int^{t_1}_{t_0}dt_2 H^I_1(t_1)H^I_1(t_2)+(\frac{-i}{\hbar})^3\int^t_{t_0}dt_1\int^{t_1}_{t_0}dt_2\int_{t_0}^{t_2}dt_3H^I_1(t_1)H^I_1(t_2)H^I_1(t_3)+\dots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-i}{\hbar})^n\int^t_{t_0}dt_1\int^{t_1}_{t_0}dt_2\dots\int^{t_{n-1}}_{t_0} dt_n H_1^I(t_1)\dots H_1^I(t_n)
$$

I tried to split $U(t,t_0)$ in terms of $U(t,t_1)U(t_1,t_2)U(t_2,t_3)\dots U(t_n,t_0)$ and let $n\to \infty$, but I failed because I know $HU$ do not commute ingeneral. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

$$U(t,t_0)=1-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_0}^tdt_{1}\,H^{I}(t_{1})U(t_{1},t_0) \tag{1}$$
Insert the equation into itself to give
$$U(t,t_0)=1-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_0}^{t}dt_{1}\,H^{I}(t_{1}) \tag{1}-\frac{1}{\hbar^{2}}\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dt_{1}\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}dt_{2}H^{I}(t_{1})H^{I}(t_{2})U(t_{2}, t_{0})$$
Once more
$$U(t,t_0)=1-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_0}^{t}dt_{1}\,H^{I}(t_{1}) \tag{1}-\frac{1}{\hbar^2}\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dt_{1}\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}dt_{2}H^{I}(t_{1})H^{I}(t_{2})+$$
$$+\frac{i}{\hbar^{3}}\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dt_{1}\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}dt_{2}\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{2}}dt_{3}H^{I}(t_{1})H^{I}(t_{2})H^{I}(t_{3})U(t_{3}, t_{0})$$
Continue inserting the equation into itself to get
$$U(t, t_{0})=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\Big)^{k}\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dt_{1}\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}dt_{2}...\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{k-1}}dt_{k}\mathcal{T}[H^{I}(t_{1})...H^{I}(t_{k})]$$

Comment: Thanks. However, I am asking whether we can get the answer by using just the flow property of U.

Comment: @Hamio Jiang You actually asked if one could use the flow property together with (1) to get it. But yes, the equation (1) easily follows from the flow property: $$U(t,t_0)=U(t_0,t_0)+ \int_{t_0}^t \frac{\partial U(t,t_0)}{\partial t}dt $$
Then plug in the flow property for the time derivative of $U$, use $U(t_0,t_0)=1$, and you should be done.